# Set to width by adjusting font size in LaTeX?

Tags: fontsize, layout

I'm trying to set a multi-line block of text with a fixed width where each line is justified by adjusting font size *without* breaking the lines.  The SILE typesetter has this feature in its `specimen` package.  Here's an example from the SILE manual:

[image]

Note each line is intact with font size adjusted to fit the width.  There are similar sounding questions out there but without the requirement to prevent breaks.  Any advice on how to do this in LaTeX?

Comment: `\resizebox{4cm}{!}{CAPERCAILLE}\\\resizebox{4cm}{!}{LAMMERGEYER}`

Comment: Thanks David!  That is a simple solution!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While it is surely possible to use something like `\obeylines` I find it easier to use a `tabular`-like construct with explicit `\\`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{libertine}% just as example

\newenvironment{scaletowidth}[1]%
{%
 \tabular{@{}
          >{\setbox0=\hbox\bgroup}
          l
          <{\egroup\resizebox{#1}{!}{\box0}}
          @{}
         }%
}{\endtabular}

\begin{document}

\begin{scaletowidth}{4cm}
CAPERCALLIE\\
LAMMERGEYERHOFEN\\
CASSOWARY\\
ACCENTOR DOWITCHER DOTTEREL
\end{scaletowidth}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Alternatively, a version which does not need explicit `\\`. This leads to a slightly different vertical spacing.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{libertine}% just as example

\newenvironment{scaletowidth}[1]%
{%
 \begingroup
 \lccode`\~=`\^^M
 \lowercase{%
    \endgroup
    \def~{%
       \def~{%
          \egroup%
          \endgraf%
          \strut\resizebox{#1}{!}{\box0}%
          \setbox0=\hbox\bgroup%
        }%
        \setbox0=\hbox\bgroup%
    }%
 }%
 \catcode`\^^M=\active
}{\egroup}

\begin{document}

\begin{scaletowidth}{4cm}
CAPERCALLIE
LAMMERGEYERHOFEN
CASSOWARY
ACCENTOR DOWITCHER DOTTEREL
\end{scaletowidth}

\end{document}
```

I don't post a further image because you wouldn't notice the difference. (But there *is*, even if minimal.)

Comment: Works great thank you!